# The multi part identifier could not be found-- order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
select d.DeviceTypeId, d.ProductTypeId, d.ModelNumber, count(d.Id) as ProductCount from SLS_Request r
inner join SLS_Device d on r.DeviceId = d.Id
where d.DeviceTypeId = 1 and r.RequestStatusId in (14, 15) -- 14=Certificate Issues, 15=Certificate Expired
group by d.DeviceTypeId, d.ProductTypeId, d.ModelNumber
--order by Max(d.EER) desc
)A
```

orderby clause is causing an error (multi part identifier could not be found) if i put it outside the subquery. Also I need to add

```
(select d.BrandNameEn,d.ModelNumber,d.FirstYearInSaudi from SLS_Device d)
```

without group by FirstYearInSaudi. Please help i am new to development.

Comment: You need `d.EER` in your select clause

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use sql window function. See the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017